# Get correct url / page to load in simple MVC

Tags: php, url, model-view-controller, url-routing

I´m making a "very" simple MVC framework in order to learn, however I have trouble getting other pages than the index page to show. In views folder I have 2 files one **index.php** and one **register.php** that I´m trying on.

I have tried various ways but can´t get my head around it. I know it is probably best to put different controller classes in different files and maybe a loader controller page but I´m a beginner with php so would like to make it as simple as possible for me...

Any help appriciated!

I have a index.php as a landing file in the root folder to bind everything together:

```
<?php
/* index.php
 * 
 */

require_once 'model/load.php';
require_once 'controller/main.php';

new mainController();
```

In the controller folder i have a file called main.php:

```
<?php
/* controller/main.php
 * 
 */


class mainController
{
    public $load;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $urlValues = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $this->urlValues = $_GET;

        //index page
        if ($this->urlValues['controller'] == "") {

        $indexPage = array("key" => "Hello");

        $this->load = new load();
        $this->load->view('index.php', $indexPage);   
        }

        //register page
        if ($this->urlValues['controller'] == "register.php") {

        $registerPage = array("key" => "Register");

        $this->load = new load();
        $this->load->view('register.php', $registerPage);   
        } 

    }
}
```

And then I have a file called load.php in the model folder:

```
<?php
/* model/load.php
 * 
 */
class load
{

    /* This function takes parameter 
     * $file_name and match with file in views.
     */

    function view($file_name, $data = null)
    {
        if (is_readable('views/' . $file_name)) {
            if (is_array($data)) {
                extract($data);
            }

            require 'views/' . $file_name;
        } else {
             echo $this->file;
                die ('404 Not Found');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

In your mainController class you don't have property with the name `urlValues`, but you use it: `$this->urlValues = $_GET;`. And what is more you have local variable with the same name, that you don't use: `$urlValues = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

And how you URL for register.php looks like?